# How is chat possible on the Xbox One / Is crossplay enabled in Gears of War 4?

Tags: pc, xbox-one, gears-of-war-4

Yesterday I was playing a ranked versus match on GoW 4 on my Xbox One and I saw a chat like interface popup where it looked like someone sent a global chat message.   I was unable to locate anywhere in the gears match interface to send a chat from my Xbox One.

**How did they send that chat message?**
**Is cross play enabled between PC and Xbox One? (and then the chat was sent from PC?)**

From all locations I could find online, cross play for competitive play is **not** enabled.  It is enabled for co-op, private versus, and horde.

Chat Message:

> [Global] *gamerTag*: lol 26% left comon

[From the Gears of War 4 site:](https://gearsofwar.com/en-us/gears-4/e3-recap)

> Versus: Train up your skills in Co-Op Versus with friends from either platform. To preserve the competitive nature of Gears and individual balance for each platform, **Crossplay is not enabled in standard Versus multiplayer.**

Several other [threads requesting](https://gearsofwar.com/en-us/forums/e9b54fc61eb74ad783d533ca502b0132/threads/please-allow-cross-play-competitive-in-gears-4/3898311f-c317-4bd4-9e14-4afe2a834f29/posts) this [feature to be enabled](https://gearsofwar.com/en-us/forums/e9b54fc61eb74ad783d533ca502b0132/threads/details-on-cross-platform-multiplayer-with-pc-and-xbox/d0deae06-185a-453e-b082-273ca8f82c77/posts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested this, and if you have a keyboard connected to your Xbox, you can use the text chat (when viewing the scoreboard at the end of a round).  It actually controls your character as well. If you plug a mouse in, I'm willing to bet you can have full PC controls on your Xbox.

You can also get an [Xbox Chatpad](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/communications/chatpad) and it'll s will work just the same. [This forum](https://gearsofwar.com/en-us/forums/e9b54fc61eb74ad783d533ca502b0132/threads/text-chat-xb1/f84a7c29-ea24-4e50-94ae-0fd1fd38322c/posts?page=1) also discusses that it is possible using the chatpad.

I've only read that cross play is allowed in coop modes only and not versus matches.

Yes... I unplugged my keyboard from my PC and plugged it into my Xbox One... but I have 2 keyboards for my PC at least.